System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException but table is exists in the database
I use Quartz to perform background tasks in my .NET core project. Here is the code for my Quartz:
public class ReportsChangesJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IReportsService _reportsService;

    public ReportsChangesJob(IReportsService reportsService)
    {
        _reportsService = reportsService;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        await _reportsService.CheckReportsChanges(context.CancellationToken);
    }
}

The method that uses this Quartz accesses the PreviousReportResult table like this:
var change = await _repository.Get<PreviousReportResult>(e => e.ReportId == report.Id);
I have an error on this line:
 Quartz.Core.ErrorLogger[0]
      Job DEFAULT.ReportsChangesJob threw an exception.
      Quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Reports.PreviousReportResult'.
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__188_0(Task`1 result)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)...

The data from the other tables that are used are obtained well. Here is the configuration code for this table:
public class PreviousReportResultConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PreviousReportResult>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PreviousReportResult> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Reports.PreviousReportResult");

        builder.HasOne(e => e.Report)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<PreviousReportResult>(e => e.ReportId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}

Next, I added this configuration to the DbContext and created a DbSet on the PreviousReportResult object.
When I try to retrieve the data in SSMS, everything works fine, the table is returned. But when I try to execute direct SQL code from my repository, I get the same error:
string sql = "SELECT TOP(1) [Id], [ItemsCount], [Json], [ReportId] FROM [Reports.PreviousReportResult] WHERE [ReportId] = @reportId";
var result = await Context.PreviousReportResults.FromSqlRaw(sql, new SqlParameter("@reportId", reportId)).ToListAsync();
return result.FirstOrDefault();

Also, here is my migration code:
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<bool>(
                name: "NotificationOnChange",
                table: "Reports.Reports",
                type: "bit",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: false);

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Reports.PreviousReportResult",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    ItemsCount = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    Json = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    ReportId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Reports.PreviousReportResult", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Reports.PreviousReportResult_Reports.Reports_ReportId",
                        column: x => x.ReportId,
                        principalTable: "Reports.Reports",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Reports.PreviousReportResult_ReportId",
                table: "Reports.PreviousReportResult",
                column: "ReportId",
                unique: true);
        }

Can you help us figure out what caused this error and how to fix it?
I tried to write separate methods that would call SQL or methods for the EntityFrameworkCore that would access the DbSet and return an object. I tried to write separate methods that would call SQL or methods for the EntityFrameworkCore that would access the DbSet and return an obj

"Reports" is the schema, not part of the table name.  You've told EF that the object name is "Reports.PreviousReportResult" and it's in the user's default schema.
If you look in SSMS you'll see that's not the case.
This
builder.ToTable("Reports.PreviousReportResult");
Should be
builder.ToTable("PreviousReportResult", schema: "Reports");

Reports.PreviousReportResult - is table name. After the database update, it is saved to the database like this: [dbo].[Reports.PreviousReportResult]. That is, the way I need it.
